# How to add space in Txt file using robotframework

Tags: robotframework

${response14}    Get WebElements    xpath=// [@id="com_ibm_team_rtc_foundation_web_ui_views_ArtifactListView_4"]
Log       ${response14}

```
         ${txt1}=    Get Text     ${response14} 
         create file   ${file2}    ${value_1}${txt}${value_11}${txt1}
         Log    ${txt1}
```

Here I want to store the value of  ${value_1}${txt}${value_11}${txt1}   in different lines in text file.
I am able to store all the values in a paragraph, but i don't want that, i need to store in different lines, How do I do this in robot framework

Comment: Did you read the docs of  `Create File` keyword? It says: Use Append To File if you want to append to an existing file. Maybe you could try `Append to File` keyword ?

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your code? It's hard to read.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert newlines using `\n`:

```
create file   ${file2}  ${value_1}\n${txt}\n${value_11}\n${txt1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
${CreatingFile} = Create File ${EXECDIR}/data/file.txt
```

Log to Console